# Script vbs para reiniciar um serviço caso ele seja "stopado"

Tags: script, batch, vbscript

Eu criei um script vbs para reiniciar o serviço caso ele estaja stopado.
Porém ele não funciona, tentei fazer um por .bat mais sem incluir no tarefas agendas.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
   & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service")

For Each objService in colRunningServices

 if (objService.State="Stopped") and (objService.DisplayName="Print Spooler") then

  Wscript.Echo "Service Status:  "& objService.State &""
  objService.StartService()
         end if  
Next
```

Comment: É um requisito utilizar o vbs? Ou pode fazer de alguma outra forma?

Comment: pode ser feito de outra formar, o vbs e o batch foram tentativas, a principio pensei que fosse o código.

Answer (score -1):

Se vc só precisa iniciar ele se estiver parado, só mande iniciar em um bat executado com permissão de administrador.

```
net start Spooler
```

Se retornar (%errorlevel%) 0 deu certo, se retornar 2 é pq aconteceu algum erro. Um dos casos de erro é se o serviço já estiver ativo. O que não seria um problema.

[Resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802207/8099197)

Answer (score -1):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Sugestão usando seu **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** adaptando a verificação do estado do serviço para quando parada startar novamente:

---

```bat
set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='Spooler'"
for each i in wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
   if i.State = "Stopped" then i.StartService
   do until wmi.ExecQuery(qry & " AND State='Running'").Count > 0
   wscript.sleep 100
   loop
next
NomeServico="Spooler de Impress"+chr(227)+"o"
for each wmi in wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
   if (wmi.State="Running") and (wmi.DisplayName=NomeServico) then
      Wscript.Echo  vbCrLf &"        Service Name: "&wmi.Name&""& vbCrLf &_
      "      Service Status: "&wmi.State&""& vbCrLf &_
      "Service Display Name: "&wmi.DisplayName&""
   end if  
next
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---